# Dynamics Crm 365 custom button on navigation tool bar

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365

In Dynamics Crm 365 (online), is it possible to create and display a custom button/icon in the navigation bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

In recent times, the global navigation bar is customizable in Ribbon workbench and buttons can be added in supported way under Mscrm.GlobalTab  [Read more](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/develop1/posts/adding-global-command-buttons-to-the-unified-interface)

[image]

———————————————————

We achieved by doing this.

Add/Use an existing ribbon/command bar button & it's Enable rule as shortcut to execute the below script as a **Function** from **javascript web resource**: [Simply copy this script, change *org_url* & run it in browser developer toolbar console to see it in action]

```
    var element = window.parent.document.getElementById("navTabGroupDiv");
    var url = "http://<org_url>/_imgs/AboutBox.gif";
    var para = document.createElement("img");
            para.id = "myimg"
            para.alt = "OhMyGod";
            para.src = url;
            para.style.float = "right";
            para.style.height = "30px";
            para.style.marginTop  = "10px";
            para.onclick = function () {
                var webResource = 'test.html';
                Xrm.Utility.openWebResource(webResource, null);
            };
            
            element.appendChild(para);
            
            var Relement = window.parent.document.getElementsByClassName("navTabFiller");
            if (Relement!=undefined && Relement.length > 0)
                Relement[0].remove();
```

[image]

Note: This DOM element manipulation is unsupported but this is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

There is no possibility to use XrmToolBox SiteMap Editor in Dynamics 365, but there is new feature. Built in SiteMap Editor. Go to Default Solution -> Apps -> and click Sales[image]

Then you can see the AppDesigner window [image]

Click Arrow away SiteMap button and thats all, you can use new SiteMap Editor[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I need the button to be available in the navigation bar (next to the search and history icons). I created an unsupported workaround attaching a script to a hidden button on the dashboard toolbar.

Comment: @noobie "attaching a script to a hidden button on the dashboard toolbar" is supported if you have done through the ribbon customization.. only injecting scripts & DOM manipulation is unsupported.