# How to hide quick form from global navigation just on web client (CRM9.x)

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365-v9

I have a CRM solution using new unified client experience. I don't want to support legacy web client. When I create form of type "quick form create" inside our solution, the form itself is being shown also in legacy web client under the "+" button.

[image: Dynamics legacy client header]

I figured out how to register custom script to say "sorry, please switch to unified client experience" but that is not very nice user experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that global Navigation bar is not customizable in a supported way. The workaround what you have is supported choice.

You can try unsupported DOM manipulation to hide that element similar to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45764439/7920473).